# Me ajudem a entender

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Uso este script para enviar informações para a api JsonPlaceholder. Gostaria de entender o porque dos seguintes trechos:

Porque devo serializar antes de usar o stringify?

```
var dados = $(this).serialize();
```

Porque no sucess eu devo colocar o 'data' dentro do function?

```
success: function(data) {
                    alert("Sucesso!")
                }
```

Segue o codigo completo e já agradeço as respostas!

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#formPost").submit(function() {
            var dados = $(this).serialize();
            console.log(dados);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
                data: JSON.stringify(dados),
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Sucesso!")
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Porque devo serializar antes de usar o stringify?"*

Para fazer a chamada `Ajax` você precisaria montar cada valor vai enviar, seja num objeto:

```
var parametros = {
   nome: 'fulano',
   idade: 18
};
```

ou numa `querystring`:

`?nome=fulano&idade=ide`

E o `serialize` irá montar isso pra você.
O `stringify` irá transformar um objeto para uma string JSON, assim por exemplo:

```
JSON.stringify({ idade: 20 });     // vai retornar '{"idade":20}'
```

No seu exemplo isso não é necessário.

*"Porque no sucess eu devo colocar o 'data' dentro do function?"*

Porque a chamada `Ajax`, em caso de sucesso, vai te retornar algo, um resultado, um objeto, e isso tem que ser posto numa variável, por isso o `success: function(data)`
Claro que `data` pode ser qualquer nome, e essa variável receberá o retorno da chamada para `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`

**EDIT** ainda estava editando a pergunta quando @dont-panic fez o comentário, que está correto, para esse exemplo não é necessário

Comment: `stringify` não é necessário depois de dar um `serialize` no formulário, sendo que: O método serialize() cria uma string de texto codificada para URL.

Comment: Obrigado e entendi muito bem sua explicação! No caso em questão, estou enviando para uma api os dados em Json e testei sem utilizar o stringify e deu certo! Pelo que entendi, o metodo 'data' ja monta o json automaticamente?

Comment: Na verdade quem monta o json de resposta é a *api*, a variável `data` recebe esse json, seria algo como:  `var data = resuladoApi("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");` isso só um exemplo ilustrativo

Comment: então o 'data' serve para 'RECEBER' a resposta e não para 'ENVIAR' a resposta, correto? No script em questão, quem monta o json para enviar para a api?

Comment: Essa linha: `var dados = $(this).serialize();` neste caso, `this`  é o formulário (`form`), ou seja, dados recebe os dados dos campos do formulário.

Comment: Obrigado brother pela ajuda!